# Fetch rows from a data frame having 2 or more same column values (conditions)

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I would like to ask how to pull/display/save in another data frame the IDs of those items whose 2 or more column values match together (Same), example: ID 1 and ID 2 has same Colour and Size value, So I want the output to display only ID 1 and 2 and so on.

Input Data

[image: Input Data]

Data Output

Only Displays those rows which match the condition as specified in question

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't post a link with the image and post the table as formatted text instead.

Comment: As Andrew mentioned, don't post images rather post text data, secondly,  also show your efforts what you have done and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a pandas DataFrame you can filter out text like

```
df[df.Color  == 'Red' and df.Price > 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but it works,

```
dataset=pd.read_csv('Stackoverflow.csv')# Your Dataset
test=dataset[dataset.Color  == 'Red']
test=test[test.Size  == 'Large']
test["IDs"]
```

[image: Code & Output]

Comment: What made you assume the OP would like to use `pd` (as opposed to e.g. Excel) ? The question needs more focus and clarification before ready to answer.

Comment: The person who posted the question didn't specified what type of dataset and what operation category to use, either make the question more direct and straight with everything need and not needed specified or either let other assume,    if information is not complete.